# Working with data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to ask for more an opinion than a question:
What would the community recommend to do when you must do a webpage with lots of data, for example, a products listing, that should have some functionality like buy (adds to cart), sorting, etc. if you have to manipulate the data of the current product - price, title, image, link and other attributes? How you do it in your projects?

For example we have a page with dozens of products, each of them has attributes: price, title, description, image(URL), link(URL). How would you store the data to use it on some user interaction? Personally, I've done it by just inserting each of the attribute in tags, something like:

```
<div class="product" data-product_id="123">
  <div class="pr_title">Title</div>
  <div class="pr_body">Body</div>
  <div class="pr_img"><img src="http://www.www.www/img.png"></div>
  <div class="pr_link"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Buy!</a></div>
</div>
```

This way I have my html structure for presentation and I worked with data in jQuery by something like:

```
var url = $('.product').find('.pr_link').find('a').attr('href');
```

But when the project got big and there were 10-15 more attributes added to each element, getting data from current product got pretty complicated and the code became mostly unreadable.

I thought of using same structure, but to keep data in some object like:

```
var products = {
    1: {
        title: "abc",
        description: "lorem ipsum",
        price: 25.19,
        img: "http://www.www.www/img.png",
        link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    }
}
```

and keep markup as simple as possible, only using elements and styles needed for design with css:

```
<div class="product" data-product_id="123">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div>Body</div>
  <img src="http://www.www.www/img.png">
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Buy!</a>
</div>
```

so `onClick` I would need to retrieve the id of the product and query it in our object "products":

```
var url = products[id].title;
```

While this is the most convenient way to work with it requires a new object.

Another idea was to keep all data in `data-` attributes of the parent div element like:

```
<div class="product" data-product_id="123" data-title="abc" data-body="Body">
```

but for much as I know jQuery doesn't work with data attributes well (natively).

So what are your suggestions? Maybe you have some even better ideas to share.

P.S. I tried to find some information on the subject, but most likely failed to find the way to formulate it well so I found nothing about it. If there are links or even similar questions on stack exchange sites, please feel free to post them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: XML or JSON? Both of those are viable...

Comment: Mostly I use JSON, but it's not about how to store data, but where to store

Comment: _"jQuery doesn't work with data attributes well"_ - Yes it does: it can retrieve them with `.attr()` or `.data()` (the latter can be less helpful since it does data conversion, so, e.g., "123" would be returned as a number not a string).

Comment: That's not a problem, thank you for correcting me.

Comment: How fast are you expecting things to get?  You still have to send all the data, and I would expect your json object to be as minimal as anything.

Comment: In my opinion it's totally depend on data. If you have small data for example suppose i do have some icon. I need to open different images on click of icons. In that case we can store it in attr like data-preview="image uri goes here".

If have little bit more meta data or data for some products. In that case we can use JSON.

But if i do have lot of products in that case i need to use XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HTML5` `data` attribute to store products data, as you have several properties of products to associate with each product block, you can `JSON encode` the object and assign to the top element, and then can access that on user interaction on that element or any child element.

```
var product = {
    title: "abc",
    description: "lorem ipsum",
    price: 25.19,
    img: "http://www.www.www/img.png",
    link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
};
$(selector).data('product',JSON.stringify(product));
```

then to retrieve the object you can do on any event's callback

```
$product = $.parseJSON($(elem).data('product'));
```

In fact both `facebook` and `twitter` used data attributes to store associated data with `tweets` and `stories`. For example here goes some html of a FB story

```
<li data-ft='{"qid":"5757245005920960301","mf_story_key":"7164261693049558180"}'
 id="stream_story_4fe5d7d51bc415443080257">
```

You can see facebook is storing JSON encoded data into the `data-ft` attribute.

Similarly an example of a Twitter `tweet` html

```
<div data-tweet-id="216534496567230464" data-item-id="216534496567230464" 
data-screen-name="onimitch" data-user-id="123682011" data-is-reply-to="">
```

So twitter is saving associated data for a tweet into different attributes like `data-tweet-id`, `data-user-id`.

So As they both handle's a lot amount of data, I think You can also use either of the method to save your data without any performance issue.

If you store data with individual keys then be aware of the automatic data conversion that `.data()` does as @nnnnnn has already mentioned in comment.

**Demo With .data() :** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vcFYj/

**Demo With .attr() :** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vcFYj/1/

Comment: Thank you, I really like and didn't know you can simply store data as JSON in an attribute, though in your example, if I understand correctly, has an error, as if you want to store a string with double quotes, attribute value should be in single quotes - data-ft='...'

Comment: @Vlakarados, yeah I know, I changed those for simplicity's sake, You dont have to worry about quotes, browser will handle those automatically.

Comment: @Vlakarados, above one is using `.data()` and http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vcFYj/1/ one is using `.attr()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this mostly covers my problem and is really an interesting way to store data, can be traversed easily, tried it myself, pretty easy to work with!

Answer (score 3):

No need to use ids or references within the DOM. Keep it clean.

Just use the data() function in jquery and bind it to the html elements. That way when you click on each element you will be able to get the object by calling this from within your click event.

```
//loop through your elements in the dom or build them dynamically. 
$.each('div.products', function(){
 $(this).data('product', <your data>);
};

//assign a handler to each element and grab the data object by using this. :)
$(container).delegate('.products', 'click' function(){
  console.log($(this).data('product'))
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend you to keep your data in an object and fill HTML with it,

There are reasons for this:

- Your data is open to all *hackers* to steal.
- When your data is too big to fetch, your page can be initially loaded without data - and it's what any web developer do not want.
- Again, when your data is too big, old computers -computers which has approx. 512M Ram- may come to a deadlock
- Again and again, when your data is too big, traversing or sorting it may costs too much time.

I understand that your data is static for minimum about 5 min.. What I recommend is,

- Place your data with Server-side languages(PHP,ASP(.NET),Python,etc.)
- Fetch data with queries seperately when your script needs it.
- Anything you do not need is cost for your user, user may have lots of page in his/her browser and it will be cause of deadlock too.

p.s. Any detail will help me to help you more.

Comment: That's correct, but the data I'm talking about is data that is displayed to the user, and only this user will see it, not anyone else. How can load times differ if I must show this data anyway? I ask for the help with organization of data, not security or performance

Comment: I see, there is a lot of way to do this as my friends said in other answers, the most powerful way is to numerate div ids. Like, <div id="product-14592">

Comment: Why is it more powerful than using data-attributes? It may be easier to select elements like that, but the whole string concatenation thing might get ridiculous, especially when you want to store more information in one tag.

Comment: The reson is in my post. It's costly to traverse all div, if you can use my method, you can reach related element at once, not just easily.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to traverse the whole object tree.
How about putting IDs:

```
<div class="pr_link" id='id_link_123'><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Buy!</a></div>
```

and retrive them as:

```
// ....
var id = 123;
// ....
var url = $("#id_title_" + id + " a").attr('href');
```

Comment: Yes, but that's like my first example, it just becomes unreadable and what's worse: un-editable later. And has another problem - if designer changes something in html - everything breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try AngularJS. It works great with jQuery and it is easy to learn. AngularJS contains two way data binding and extends HTML by new attributes and elements. Last but not least it is MVC framework by Google. See more at http://www.angularjs.com

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, looks promising, something similar to knockout.js as I see. But this is something different than the actual question, the question is looking for a way to store dynamic data so that the code to use it(read, write, change) would be readable, as you can see, I tagged jQuery, that's the requirement for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are many excellent clientside mvc frameworks, check out [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), which is a powerful-but-easy-to-use framework for managing the interface between your data source (usually an http server), and your DOM. In short, it keeps "[your truth out of the DOM](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Getting-Truth-Out-of-the-DOM/)"

As a contrived example, if you are creating a simple address book app, you would probably have a clientside `Contact` Backbone model, which would roughly (or exactly) mirror the model you have on your server.

Backbone manages requesting and parsing the contact data (json, xml, etc) from the server (or localstorage, etc) into these `Contact` model objects, and you provide a js callback to update your DOM when changes occur. This also works in reverse: Backbone updates the server when the model objects change, either instantly, after some delay, or when you explicitly call the `save` function.

Backbone might not be the correct framework for you. But check them all out before you decide to roll your own solution. Even so, you could create your own clientside MVC layer, if you feel you:

- Can do a better job than one of the many excellent existing javascript MVC frameworks,
- Have such a unique problem that only a bespoke solution will work for you, or
- Find clientside MVC, or javascript frameworks somehow scary or distasteful.

Comment: Thank you, to my mind this is a great alternative to the answer above. though it looks like it's pretty complicated to use on not-so-big projects I find this to be the second best answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree to Enes, you shouldnt embed your data into the jquery code or, as you already mentioned, your code will quickly become so complex as to be unsupportable.  An MVC framework will help with this.

There are a couple mentioned in the answers above such as http://angularjs.com and http://backbonejs.org although i cant vouch for either of them but you should have a look to see if they help solve your problems.

I am currently rewriting a scrumwall application i originally developed in jquery and raw php into the [agile toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org).  With agiletoolkit (aka atk4 on stackoverflow), you define models which map to the database tables, html templates and views which have placeholders where you want the data to go and pages where you add models, forms and grids.  It provides the links between javascript and php and has features including ajax refreshes of views.

You could use html5 features but only the latest browsers will support this so you may have problems if the users are not in a controlled environment (e.g. a single company where there is a standard web browser).

Comment: A great tip, but I use CodeIgniter, that's why I can't use agile toolkit, thank you for you answer, someone may find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

The combination of DOM and jQuery is one of the most powerful things the Web has. You are not taking all of them.

Make the DOM help you and work for you. Organize better the DOM. Take all of it. Your example can be optimized this way:

```
<div class="product" data-product_id="123">
  <div class="pr_title">Title</div>
  <div class="pr_body">Body</div>
  <img class="prodcut-image" src="http://www.www.www/img.png">
  <a class="product-link" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Buy!</a>
</div>
```

To select with jQuery, simple write:

```
var url = $('.product .product-link').attr('href');
```

I believe that your problem is that your are forgetting the way CSS selectors work. It's not necessary to transverse into every level of the DOM.

You can take off some DIV's in your example. A link not necessary have to be in-line. A CSS rule can make them work like a DIV.

Comment: That was just an example, you started to talk about the point of the question, but ended up by taking my code as real code that should be optimized, when the projects get bigger and more complicated, by no chance you will be left with such simple markup, especially when the designer is a perverted freak :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use (as you already are) the data- attributes in HTML through jQuery. When you create the DIV from the server data, you can do something like this:

```
$('.product').data(yourProduct); // yourProduct would be the JSON representation of the data
```

To retrieve:

```
var url = $('product').data('product-link'); // if the JSON object has a product-link property that is.
```

The caveat someone mentioned above that your data is exposed to the browser is of course still valid, so take care.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter in any way, the product information is available for everyone even in not js online shops